# String replace from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response that is not properly formatted and has speical characters coming in and I want to clean it up by removing the special characters using string.replace(). For some reason it is not working.

Here is the JSON result

```
[{"User::newPassword":["Password could not be changed. The request can't be validated"]},[]]
```

and here is my expression.

```
resp.replace(::g, '');
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any advice on this would be appreciated as there is nothing I can do for it on the backend.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `replace()` on JSON.

**If you're working with strings**

`::` should be in quotes if you want to replace first occurrence of it.

```
resp.replace('::', '');
```

If you want to replace all occurrences, use `/` as delimiter of regex.

```
resp.replace(/::/g, '');
```

**If you're working with JSON**

1. Convert the `JSON` to string using `JSON.stringify()`
2. Use `replace` on string
3. Convert `string` back to `JSON` using `JSON.parse()`

**Using Object methods**

You can also change the `key` to remove `::` from it

```
var newKey = key.replace('::', ''); // Create new key by replacing the `::`
obj[newKey] = obj[key]; // Add new key and value in object
delete key; // Remove old key
```